# How do I get the bar graph to sit at the bottom of the picture box?

Tags: c#, drawrectangle

I've been trying for hours but can't seem to figure it out. How can I get the bar-graph to sit on the bottom of the picture box without instead of it hanging from the top. Here is a picture of what it looks like so far. I've tried changing the Y position but it just moves the whole graph downwards rather then inverting it.

I want to take the distance walked and display it in a bar graph using the DrawRectangle, DrawLine Method. Here are the two methods I am using to draw the bar graph:

Method to retrieve data from list then display as bar graph in picture box:

```
private void DrawBarGraph()
    {
        Graphics canvas = pictureBoxTop.CreateGraphics();
        int x = 200;
        int y = 0;
        foreach (int i in distanceList)
        {
            int length = SCALE_FACTOR * i;
            DrawABar(canvas, x, y, length , Color.Red);
            x += BAR_WIDTH + GAP;
        }             
    }
```

Method to draw bars:

```
private void DrawABar(Graphics paper, int x, int y, int length, Color colour)
    {
        //create a brush of specified colour and fill background with this colour 
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colour);
        paper.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, BAR_WIDTH, length);

        //draw outline in black
        paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x, y, BAR_WIDTH, length);
    }
```

[Bar graph drawing with DrawRectangle method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABh7t.png)

Answer (score 0):

OP's solution (extracted from question post)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Draw a bar graph in the picture box
    /// </summary>
    private void DrawBarGraph()
    {
        Graphics canvas = pictureBoxTop.CreateGraphics();
        // Set world transform of graphics object to translate.
        canvas.TranslateTransform(1200.0F, 195.0F);

        // Then to rotate, prepending rotation matrix.
        canvas.RotateTransform(180.0F);
        //set row and column length then allocate colors to specific columns
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        foreach (int i in distanceList)
        {
            int length = SCALE_FACTOR * i;
            DrawABar(canvas, x, y,length , Color.Red);
            x += BAR_WIDTH + GAP;
        }               
    }
```

After a couple of google searches and a bit more playing around I came across two methods designed to rotate the images inside of a picture box.

Here is the picture below:
[Inverted bar graph using RotateTransfrom and RotateFlip Properties.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVG3E.png)